httpx.ConnectError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
it is not working in vscode its while working with python and streamlit
I expecting port number while running in the vscode to redirect the browser to run out commands to get output . while giving the prompt its automatically give the answer

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
